# Can I run 'apt install' inside LXD containers on Ubuntu Core host?

Tags: ubuntu-core, lxd

Reading [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/701626/301931) we can apparently install LXD as a snap package on Ubuntu Core. Knowing the [limitation of Ubuntu Core](https://askubuntu.com/a/594212/301931), I'm wondering whether it's a possibility to run "normal" Ubuntu Server LXD containers on a Ubuntu Core host? E.g. can you run `apt install` commands in the container to install Apache web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you can.** If you spin up Ubuntu server in an LXD container on a snappy system, you can run `apt install` inside that lxd container.

You can see LXD containers as virtual machines that use the same kernel as the host. Ubuntu Core has the same kernel as Ubuntu server. This means that **there is no difference between running LXD containers on Ubuntu Core and running LXD containers on Ubuntu Server.** *Note that a webserver running in an LXD container is not accessible from outside the host by default. You will need to forward a port from the host to the container, or connect the container directly to the host network and give it an IP on the host's network.*

The `classic` snap might also be useful to you. [The classic snap](https://github.com/snapcore/classic-snap) is an entire Ubuntu Server packaged as a snap. You can install stuff with `apt` inside the snap. See the following example:

```
$ sudo snap install --beta --devmode classic
$ sudo classic
(classic)ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo apt update
...
(classic)ubuntu@localhost:~$ exit
```

A webserver in the classic snap is accessible from outside by default. However, daemons are not started in the classic snap and all running background binaries will stop when you exit the classic snap.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the lxd snap as `snap install lxd`. `apt install` is **not** supported in Ubuntu Core. For installing other applications, you can either-

- package them as a snap
- run a Ubuntu LXD Container and apt install anything inside
- install the `classic` snap and apt install anything inside

Comment: You're answering my question with **run a Ubuntu LXD Container and apt install anything inside**. This wasn't a given for me, I know I could try it out on my RPi but I'm not willing to spend the time atm. How sure are you that this is the reality? I.e. running "normal" Ubuntu Server on top of Ubuntu Core?

Comment: Ubuntu Server is *not* a single package. If you wish to install a certain package from the Server distribution, you can easily do that with one of the options above.